# Webpack including unused exports in final bundle (not tree shaking)

Tags: webpack, webpack-3, tree-shaking

I have a setup where a library's index.js (main entry point) exports everything in the lib... so its setup like this:

```
export * from "./mod1"
export * from "./mod2"
// etc...
```

([take a look](https://github.com/purtuga/common-micro-libs/blob/master/src/index.js))

When I import 1 of the exported libraries from that entry point, looks like Webpack is not able to tree-shake the output.  running `webpack -p` is actually including the entire library in the bundle, although only one export was imported. Runing `webpack` (non-production bundle) does show `unused harmony export ....` throughout the file (167 times), but why are they not being dropped?

I have a test setup showing this problem here: https://github.com/purtuga/webpack-bundle-test

Hoping someone (smarter than me :) ) can help identify what I am doing wrong.

/Paul

Comment: Have you found a better solution to this? I'm facing the exact same problem.

Comment: I have sense moved to Webpack 4 and I think I'm no longer having this issue - but: I have not circled back around to it to validate (using the test project I setup). If I have some time, I will do that and report back here.

Comment: I have opened a new post with my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55320774/webpack-tree-shaking-not-working-between-packages

Comment: Thanks  @Apidcloud . I will follow that one as well and have also shared your question on Twitter to see if we get a broader community to look at it.

Answer (score 3):

I cloned your "webpack-bundle-test" and here is what i did.

1. Copied "common-micro-libs" src folder from https://github.com/purtuga/common-micro-libs.
2. Edited the code in mod3.js to: `import { objectExtend } from "./common-micro-libs"
   export default mod3 = objectExtend({}, { text: "module 3" });`
3. I ran `webpack` locally and found 167 "unused harmony" comments.
4. With `webpack -p` i got the following results:
   [image]
5. Changed code in mod3.js to `import objectExtend from "./common-micro-libs/jsutils/objectExtend.js"
   export default mod3 = objectExtend({}, { text: "module 3" });`.
6. With the above change i could see the following reduction in bundle size[image]

I believe when importing dependencies, it is better to import only the necessary function/component from the library and this will be packed more effectively in the bundle.
I am not able to expalin why so, though i followed the same principle in importing utilities in my project when using lodash and it works fine.
Can you run the tests and let me know?

Comment: Hi Priyesh - thanks for the response. I been importing dependencies from the single `lib-name/src/.../` file for a while - so I know that works. But I was trying to keep the right side of `from` short by only using the library package name and have the named imports be retrieved from there (`import { foo } from "lib-name"` - and thats when I found this issue - for which I'm looking to understand Why its happening. I'm not sure who is at fault: is it webpack in the way it defined unused `harmony` imports in the bundle (thus Uglify is not able to drop them) or is it Uglify?  Thanks for trying

Comment: Have you found a better way? I'm having the same issue :/

Comment: In [webpack 4's treeshaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) you can not set the "sideEffects" property in your package.json.
These provides hints to webpack compiler on "dead code"

Answer (score 1):

When you bundle the application without transformations (like Babel) and minification (like UglifyJS), you get: *unused harmony export*.

Now Webpack 2+ only marks code unused and doesn’t export it inside the module. It pulls everything and leaves unused code for minification libraries.

You can use [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) with babel for this.
UglifyJS doesn’t support the new language features of Javascript ES2015+ yet. You will need Babel to transpile the code to ES5 and then use UglifyJS to clean up the unused code.

You will need .babelrc file with:

We have to tell the preset (in our case [babel-preset-env](https://github.com/babel/minify)) to skip the module transpilation.

```js
    {
      "presets": [
        ["env", {
          "loose": true,
          "modules": false
        }]
      ]
    }
```

and corresponding webpack config:

```js
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
      ]
    },
    
    plugins: [
      new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: true,
        debug: false
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
          warnings: true
        },
        output: {
          comments: false
        },
        sourceMap: false
      })
    ]
```

**OR**

[Babili](https://github.com/babel/minify) is a better option since Babili will remove unused code before transpilation. It is much easier to spot unused classes before downleveled to ES5. Tree-shaking will also work for class declarations, not just functions.

You will need:

```
npm install [babili][3] [babili-webpack-plugin][4] --save-dev
```

Use the following plugin in your webpack config, like so:

```js
    plugins: [
      new BabiliPlugin()
    ]
```

There is also an optimzied way to use babili as a preset. You can refer their site to use it as a preset for babel-loader.

Comment: thank you for your response... But this does not help. Yes, I do understand how tree shaking is actually accomplished.. and all that you describe above is true with my example (take a look a the test git repo I provided) - so I was expecting the "dead code" to be dropped when the package was minified (`webpack -p`) - but thats the not the case...  I'm really stumped on this one...